# Python prints to the terminal despite being run in the background

Tags: python, terminal

How can I avoid python printing to the terminal when running in the background?  I want it to print when run in the foreground or piped to another file, which it does successfully, but not print when run in the background.

For example, I have a file testing.py. With one line:
`print("This is just a test")`
If I run in the terminal
`>python testing.py`
It gives me:
`This is just a test`
However, if I run the script in the background,
`python testing.py &`
I still get
`This is just a test`
printed to the terminal, directly into my command prompt.

Comment: Where do you expect print() to send the text to if not the console?

Comment: You can pipe the output to dev/null, maybe?

Comment: This is really a question about the terminal shell, not python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do

```
python testing.py > /dev/null &
```